# Checked parent checkbox if all child checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check parent node if all child node are checked. I have found some solutions on this particular topic as well. But, may be because of different nesting levels I am unable to achieve this.

Upto this point, I am able to check / uncheck child node according to the parent node. However, reverse is not working i.e, checking parent node if all child nodes are checked.

### My Html

```
<ul class="treeview">
   <li id="li_1" class="contains-items">
      <div class="checkbox">
         <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="categories[]">
         <label for="1">
         Floor
         </label>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li class="li_1">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="4" type="checkbox" value="4" name="categories[]">
               <label for="4">
               1st Floor
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="li_1">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="5" type="checkbox" value="5" name="categories[]">
               <label for="5">
               2nd Floor
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="li_1">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="6" type="checkbox" value="6" name="categories[]">
               <label for="6">
               3rd Floor
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="li_2">
      <div class="checkbox">
         <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="2" name="categories[]">
         <label for="2">
         Rent
         </label>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li id="li_3" class="contains-items">
      <div class="checkbox">
         <input id="3" type="checkbox" value="3" name="categories[]">
         <label for="3">
         View
         </label>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li class="li_3">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="7" type="checkbox" value="7" name="categories[]">
               <label for="7">
               Pool View
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="li_3">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="categories[]">
               <label for="8">
               Mountain View
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="li_3">
            <div class="checkbox">
               <input id="9" type="checkbox" value="9" name="categories[]">
               <label for="9">
               Courtyard
               </label>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
            // if is checked
            if($(this).is(':checked')){

                // check all children
                $(this).parent().siblings().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);

                //if all siblings are checked, check its parent checkbox
                if($(this).parent().siblings('li input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {  
                    console.log('all siblings checked');
                    //check its parent checkbox
                }else{
                    console.log('not all siblings checked');
                }

            } else {

                // uncheck all children
                $(this).parent().siblings().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);

            }

        });
```

However, even doing this it is always consoling `not all sibilings checked` even if all are checked.

Comment: *I am trying to check parent node...* how can that happen ? Do you mean a checkbox that becomes checked when all the other checkboxes are checked ? Also, what element is the *parent node* ?

Comment: Example, here Floor is parent of 1st floor, 2nd floor and 3rd floor. Parent means just one level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it easier I removed the "display: none;" style.

The way you use to test if all siblings are checked is wrong.

The updated snippet:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    // if is checked
    if(this.checked){
        // check all children
        var lenchk = $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox');
        var lenchkChecked = $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox:checked');

        //if all siblings are checked, check its parent checkbox
        if (lenchk.length == lenchkChecked.length) {
            $(this).closest('ul').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        }else{
            $(this).closest('.checkbox').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        }
    } else {
        // uncheck all children
        $(this).closest('.checkbox').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).closest('ul').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="treeview">
    <li id="li_1" class="contains-items">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="categories[]">
            <label for="1">
                Floor
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul >
            <li class="li_1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="4" type="checkbox" value="4" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="4">
                        1st Floor
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li_1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="5" type="checkbox" value="5" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="5">
                        2nd Floor
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li_1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="6" type="checkbox" value="6" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="6">
                        3rd Floor
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="li_2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="2" type="checkbox" value="2" name="categories[]">
            <label for="2">
                Rent
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="li_3" class="contains-items">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="3" type="checkbox" value="3" name="categories[]">
            <label for="3">
                View
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="li_3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="7" type="checkbox" value="7" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="7">
                        Pool View
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li_3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="8">
                        Mountain View
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li_3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="9" type="checkbox" value="9" name="categories[]">
                    <label for="9">
                        Courtyard
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @gaetanoM it looks great however, after checking all three child i.e. 1st floor , 2nd floor and 3rd floor, when I uncheck one then all three are being unchecked ,and whenever any of the child is unchecked I want to uncheck the parent node as well. Could you help on that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.branch` to the `UL` element that is the parent of the checkboxes "siblings" and do like:

```js
$('.treeview').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {

  const $ul = $(this).closest('ul')

  if ($ul.is('.treeview')) { // Main checkbox handler: 
  
    const $group = $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox');
    $group.prop('checked', this.checked);

  } else { // Group checkboxes handler:

    const $group  = $ul.find(':checkbox');
    $ul.closest('li').find(':checkbox:first').prop('checked', !$group.filter(':not(:checked)').length);
    
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="treeview">
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="floor" name="categories[]">Floor</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label><input  type="checkbox" value="floor_1" name="categories[]">1st Floor</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="floor_2" name="categories[]">2nd Floor</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="floor_3" name="categories[]">3rd Floor</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="rent" name="categories[]">Rent</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="view" name="categories[]">View</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="view_pool" name="categories[]">Pool</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="view_mountain" name="categories[]">Mountain</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="view_courtyard" name="categories[]">Courtyard</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: the above is not recursive and will work for single depth.

Comment: looks great. However, I don't want to hide child node even if parent is unchecked. Could you make that small tweak?

Comment: @AayushDahal yes, if you explain the logic of hiding/showing.

Comment: Example, when floor is unchecked, still I want to show 1st floor , 2nd floor and 3rd floor check box. Currently in your solution, its hiding when floor is unchecked

Comment: my bad it was because of my code of hiding it. Although, I had some other techniques to show/hide maybe when I copy element by inspect element that property comes as well. However, Main problem: - I Don't want to check parent node if not all of its child are checked. Currently, the parent checkbox is checked when one of its child is checked or so.